# How to "emulate" C++ reference in python?

Tags: python

For example, I may want to write the following code:

```
def is_good(args, status):
  if ....
    status[0] = 'somevalue'
    return True
  return False
```

And call it by

```
status = 'somedefault'
some_var = is_good(..., [status])
```

Hence status can be modified when needed, just like passing a C++ reference.

However, the code seems not reader-friendly. Is there more pythonic way to do this?

Comment: Return the result and `status` as a tuple.

Comment: This `[status]` technique doesn't work, you realize? `status` isn't being modified by `is_good`, only the temporary list.

Answer (score 1):

python arguments are mutable, this makes your code more readable.
if you really need a function that changes a value you can exploit the fact that a function can return a tuple hence (BTW, I find this code much more readable as it tells explicitly what it does and doesn't force you to read the function to know that it actually changes `status`):

```
def is_good(args, status):
  if ....
    status[0] = 'somevalue'
    return (True, status)
  return (False, status)
```

and then:

```
some_var, status = is_good(..., [status])
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
status = 'somedefault'
```

use

```
# or rename it statusPtr if you want to remember to "dereference" it
status = ['somedefault']
```

**Alternatively**, if you want to save on key strokes and you have a lot of these references and you plan to use them a lot, then you can define a Ref class:

```
class Ref:
    def __init__(s, v=None): 
        s.v = v
```

Then "declare" (instantiate really) `status` as

```
status = Ref('somedefault')
```

or

```
status = Ref()
status.v = 'somedefault'
```

and then use it like this:

```
def is_good(args, status):
    if ....
        status.v = 'somevalue'
        return True
    return False
```